# OPENSSL connection to a public server gives X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I am writing a very basic SSL client to connect to a HTTPS web server.  I can connect and process the request/response just fine.  However OpenSSL is reporting `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY`, but so far I choose to ignore the error :-).  Now I want to solve that part of the problem.

I am testing by connecting to a public SSL server on HTTPS, such as Google or Yahoo, and checking the return of `SSL_get_verify_result(...)`.

As I understand it, I need the CA pem files for that specific site so that OpenSSL can verify the chain to a trusted certificate authority.  In this case, that would be the authority that signed the certs for Google or Yahoo.

To get the PEM files which I expect should work, I opened my FireFox, navigated to those sites, and performed a View Certificate and exported each one up the list.  So for example, I have a file called "GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem"  which all looks good.  In fact, when I went to the GeoTrust site directly and downloaded their root certificate, it is identical to the one I exported from FireFox, as I would expect.

So, for example with Google which showed two certificates in the tree in FireFox, I load each one with:

```
result = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"GoogleInternetAuthorityG2.pem",NULL);
if (result == 0) {
    puts("Opps...  Can't load the certificate");
}

result = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem",NULL);
if (result == 0) {
    puts("Opps...  Can't load the certificate");
}
```

After that, the usual stuff to connect and communicate:

```
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "www.google.com:https");
```

And get no errors when loading or connecting.

However, the verification does not work.

```
result = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
printf("The Verify Result is %d \n",result);
```

I get the return `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY (error code 20)`.

So, am I missing some concept here?  Wouldn't this give me the `X509_V_OK` result because it has the trusted certificates?  There were only two that were up the chain from google.com, and I used them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second call to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` is replacing the certificate from the first call.

You should combine your roots into a single file:

```
$ cat my-trusted-roots.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (CA certificate in base64 encoding) ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (CA certificate in base64 encoding) ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (CA certificate in base64 encoding) ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And then load that single file with `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`. See the OpenSSL [docs on `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html). In partuclar, the ***NOTES*** section:

> If CAfile is not NULL, it points to a file of CA certificates in PEM
>   format. The file can contain several CA certificates identified by
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> ... (CA certificate in base64 encoding) ...
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> sequences. Before, between, and after the certificates text is allowed
>   which can be used e.g. for descriptions of the certificates.

---

Just bike shedding here...

```
result = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
printf("The Verify Result is %d \n",result);
```

That's one of three tests you need to perform.

The second test you need to perform is below. Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH) does not use a certificate, so you need to check for that.

```
X509* cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
if(cert) X509_free(cert);

if(cert == NULL)
    /* Error - Anonymous Diffie-Hellman */
```

`SSL_get_peer_certificate` bumps the reference count on the certificate, so you need a matching call to `X509_free`.

The third test you need to perform is hostname matching. OpenSSL 1.1.0 *WILL* perform hostname matching (and other name matching, like PKCS9 email addresses); but lesser versions, like 0.9.8 and 1.0.1, *DO NOT* perform the matching.

Comment: I appreciate this (I am not getting emails that there was an answer... maybe I should post a question about that :-).  As for checking the peer certificate, doesn't only apply if I want to verify the client?  If I'm allowing anonymous clients, but just want to avoid sniffing, it's not required is it?

Comment: (yes, this is test is as client, just asking because I will eventually need to support both types)

Comment: As a additional problem, this works fine with "google", however when I use our company website, I still get the error code 20 on the `SSL_get_verify_result()` call.  Is this a result of our using a "wildcard" certificate?  _*.domain.com_.  The version of OpenSSL I am currently using is 1.0.1g

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this post I could finally get the [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) to work on Windows. I [built openssl using MSYS2](https://wiki.qt.io/Compiling_OpenSSL_with_MinGW). I had to make some changes to the [openssl-bio-fetch.tar.gz](https://wiki.openssl.org/images/d/dc/Openssl-bio-fetch.tar.gz) code so it could build/run in Windows/MSYS2, mostly adjusting the Makefile includes and setting -DNDEBUG to avoid the Posix signals.

However when running the code I got:

```
    $ ./openssl-bio-fetch.exe
    Warning: thread locking is not implemented
    verify_callback (depth=1)(preverify=0)
        Issuer (cn): DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
        Subject (cn): DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
        Error = X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
    certificate verify failed
```

I had to download the 2 .pem files:

[DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA](https://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt.pem)

[DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA](https://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2ExtendedValidationServerCA.crt.pem)

**AND PASTE THE CERTIFICATES TO THE SAME .pem FILE ALREADY IN USE BY THE CODE: random-org-chain.pem**

Thank You!